# Angular min date validation incorrect for any year before 1901

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

Any help or explanation for this would be really appreciated. I've got to believe this is an issue with my implementation because otherwise it seems like a huge bug in Angular.

**Setup**

Define a form with a min date of **0001-01-01** (to get around [this Android date performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303615/why-has-chrome-on-androids-native-html5-date-picker-become-really-slow))

```
<input type="date" min="0001-01-01" max="9999-12-31"/>
```

**Problem**

Now the date control does not believe any dates prior to 1901 to be valid e.g. 1800

**Additional Info**

Replicated using Angular's own date [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jPICFoUXTKtAwoVsq6bF?p=preview).

I also found that a min year of 0100 made 1800 valid, while a min year of 0010 made 1800 *not*.

Any way around this?

Comment: By your info, setting your mindate to something reasonable would be a way around this issue. Unless you're building an archive on dates of notable historical documents, I don't think it's useful to accept a date that's over 1000 years old.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks yeah I realise that's an option for a workaround - I just didn't want to resort to that until I'd bottomed out the issue. That said I don't think we can assume that there will never be a need to record a date prior to 100AD. What if I wanted to build a history website?

Comment: Never being able to record BC dates in a history website sounds like a much bigger downside than only recording up to 100AD. We just need to accept that there's limitations to what exists already and for specialised use cases we probably need to resort to building our own solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of js dates, you will end up pulling your hair out.

```
console.log(new Date('01/01/10'));
Fri Jan 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West-Europa (standaardtijd))

console.log(new Date('01/01/100'));
Fri Jan 01  100 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West-Europa (standaardtijd))

console.log(new Date('01/01/0001'));
Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West-Europa (standaardtijd))
```

I think `new Date('01/01/100')` is the lowest possible JS date. (timezone excluded)